# Mybatis sqlsession unable to rollback

Tags: java, spring, oracle11g, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm working in `Spring` project, using `mybatis 3` and `oracle 11g`.

I tried to `rollback transactions` when errors happen. However, rollback seems not to be working.

Source code bellow:

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

**Service**

```
int changeLimitSrcAcc(String src_acctno,String dest_acctno, String amt);
```

**ServiceImpl**

```
    @Override
    public int changeLimitSrcAcc(String src_acctno, String dest_acctno,
            String amt) {
        int result = 0;
        SqlSessionFactory sqlMapper = MyBatisService.getSessionFactory();
        SqlSession sqlSession = sqlMapper.openSession();
        CustomerAccountMapper mapper = sqlSession
                .getMapper(CustomerAccountMapper.class);

        try {
            int result1 = mapper.changeLimitSrcAcc(src_acctno, amt);
            int result2 = mapper.changeLimitDescAcc(dest_acctno, amt);
            if (result1 != 1 || result2 != 1)
                throw new Exception("Error happened");
            else result = 1;
            sqlSession.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            sqlSession.rollback();
        } finally {
            sqlSession.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I also tried to `rollback` a single `transaction` but it still committed.

I read on Mybatis home page and it said `@transaction` annotations doesn't need. I also put the `annotations` and nothing happened.

Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I would try the `@Transactional` annotation and let the method throw the exception instead of catching it. In this case you shouldn't need the `SqlSessionFactory` or the `SqlSession`, but can inject the mapper directly and Spring should take care of the rest. See the Spring documenation: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: You are declaring a transaction manager outside Mybatis, so you can not use the SqlSession commit() or rollback(). Use instead the commit/rollback method asociated with the spring transaction manager as Florian Schaetz says.

Comment: Using @Transactional in the Service methods should defenitely work for you. Well, it worked for me fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways of managing transactions:

1. `Declarative Transaction Management` (`@Transactional` annotation)
2. `Programmatic Transaction Management` (manually do commit/rollback)

You try to do both. Decide - either let Spring manage transactions - [configure myBatis with Spring config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651318/spring-service-transactional-doesnt-rollback-transaction-mybatis-sqlsession/42729257#42729257) - more simple way or [manually create `DefaultTransactionDefinition`](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/transactions.html) etc.